# setting label to link in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, label, href

I'm trying to set a label to a link to open an image. 
I was using asp.net in the code behind to do this:

```
lblFile1.Text = "<a href=\"/utilities/ViewPDF.aspx?ImageName=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logo2ImageFolder"] + Company.Current.CompCode + "\\" + f.File1 + "\" target=\"blank\">View File</a>";
```

But now I need to change this to JavaScript, so when they click link the label it opens the link.

I tried this but the label doesn't even display:

```
document.getElementById('lblFile1').value = "<a href=\"/utilities/ViewPDF.aspx?ImageName= + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['Logo2ImageFolder'] + Company.Current.CompCode + '\\' + " + result.File1 + "\" target=\"blank\">View File</a>";
```

I'm using `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFile1"></asp:Label>`

The link did work when I was using it in the code behind but it's not working in JavaScript.

Comment: when your javascript run what output u received ?

Comment: i think this will help you.use id like this  <%=lblFile1.ClientID%>.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya making that change didn't work

Comment: @SunilKumar output of what? result.File1 is equal to name of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById('lblFile1').value
```

to

```
document.getElementById('lblFile1').innerHTML
```

This allows the contents of your label (an HTML span) to interpret the HTML link you place inside.

Also check your output because ASP.NET may be changing your asp:Label ID at output. Setting the ClientIDMode to "static" will solve the issue. Make sure your chosen ID doesn't conflict with any other nodes having the same ID.